# How to make selected item remain inside its source with appendTo?

Tags: jquery

There are two `select` elements and buttons between them :

[image]

```
$('#btnOne').click(function() { // ">"
        return !$('#produits option:selected').appendTo('#produit');
    });
```

For example in this image how to make the "Jengy" option **not removed** from the first listbox ?

Comment: use jQuery UI instead...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LauR6/ Free jsFiddle for you.Enjoy :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`append` and `appendTo` moves the element if it already exists in the DOM, if you want to keep the original *and* create a new one, you have to `clone` it ?

```
$('#btnOne').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var clone = $('#produits option:selected').clone();
    clone.appendTo('#produit');
});
```

Comment: you're absolutely right that you understood the OP.